# Read Email or Not | in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, wiki

I want to know if the person read the mail or not..
It works well if person click on a link inside the mail.
But I want to make it work without a link, so I have to add a picture `<img>`.
But in this case does not work.

```php
$message = '<p> confirm </p> <img src="'. base_url().'Email/Track_Open_Email/'.$toEmail.'" width="80" height="80" />';
//Email{Controller}/Track_Open_Email{Method}/toEmail{First Param}
```

`Track_Open_Email` function in Email Controller

```php
public function Track_Open_Email ($email)
{  
  $this->Email_model->Set_Track_Open_Email($email , $data);
}// from here will go to Email model
```

Comment: Most email clients prevent external images from loading by default to stop people tracking if the email has been opened or not.

Comment: that's true, but it's a separate problem and not the point of the question the OP asked. Yes, a disclaimer must be made stating that tracking open rates is not perfect, but that shouldn't stop us from pointing the OP in the right direction in terms of how to solve the problem he's facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing a parameter as an URI element in CI doesn't automatically convert it into the variable the function expects.

I suggest this:

```
public function Track_Open_Email ($email)
{  
   // this will take https://domain.tld/controller/track_open_email/email_address and 
   assign email_address to $email:
   $email = $this->uri->segment(3);

   $this->Email_model->Set_Track_Open_Email($email , $data);
}
```

Be advised that this exact code requires the url helper to be loaded beforehand and has a small caveat: since you are only checking the email address, if you have multiple different emails sent to the same recipient, reading one will mark all of them as read.

My suggestion would be to pass another parameter (for instance `<img src="'. base_url().'Email/Track_Open_Email/'.$toEmail.'/.$email_id.'" width="80" height="80" />` ) on each different mailing so that by parsing `$this->uri->segment(3)` and `$this->uri->segment(4)` and assign each to a separate value you can mark only that specific mail as read:

```
public function Track_Open_Email ($email)
{  
   // this will take https://domain.tld/controller/track_open_email/email_address/email_id and 
   assign email_address to $email:

   $email = $this->uri->segment(3);
   $email_id = $this->uri->segment(4);

   // now pass both params to the Set_Track_Open_Email model:
   $params = array('email'=>$email, 'email_id'=>$email_id);
   $this->Email_model->Set_Track_Open_Email($params , $data);
}
```

Finally, in the model run an update query using both params (you'll access them as `$params['email']` and `$params['email_id']` and mark only the specific email was read by that specific user.

For clarity: `$email_id` should have a value that uniquely identifies the "campaign" for lack of a better word. So, if today you send an email to all your 10,000 users informing them of something, those 10,000 emails sent would have the same email_id (it could be anything: a nonce, a hash with the sending date, or whatever as long as no other email has the same). If you send another email to your users tomorrow, that email would have a different email_id.
What do you accomplish with that? If I read your first mail, I only get marked as having read the first mail, not both. A second benefit is that you could track open rates for each mail separately.

Comment: it is work , but the content image show as blocked content , so i have to click show blocked content to make the content view then the Function will work .. what i can to do to avoid this ??  https://e.top4top.net/p_1019una0k1.png

Comment: You can't... that's one of the reasons why tracking open rates is far from perfect. This is a setting that depends on the recipient's email client (most will block automatic display of external content for privacy) as @Quentin noted in the comments under your original question. This will work as long as each recipient permits the display of external content/images and it's totally outside of the sender's control

Comment: furthermore, in this case you're being flagged as spam which doubles the chance that external content will not be displayed automatically. One way to reduce the odds of being flagged as spam is to use an email delivery service (Mailgun, SendGrid or many others) but keep in mind that all of those require some implementation on your side in addition to payment after a small number of mails sent each month.